# Dynamically assign styles to DOM Element in Polymer 3.0

Tags: vue.js, polymer, polymer-3.x

I'm building a component in Polymer 3.0 for the first time, and I was wondering how to dynamically assign styles to a DOM element. I am building a horizontal timeline of events, and I would like to place vertical markers at every year in set range. In `Vue.js`, I would do something like this:

```
<year-marker v-for="(year, index) in years" :style="getPercentFromLeft(year)" :key="index"></year-marker>
```

In this setup, I would have a data structure with all the years that I want to display, and the v-for would loop through that data structure and render a markers for every year. 
The `getPercentFromLeft` function would calculate the percent from the left side of the screen that the marker should be positioned. The return value is in the format of `{left: 10%}`. The `year-marker` has additional styles, but they are specified in the style section.

What is the equivalent way to do this in `Polymer 3.0`? If there isn't one, what is a better way to do this?

Comment: Yes, you can have iterations and computed styles on child elements in Polymer, it's just a different syntax, check the docs. There are a few options for example https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/3.0/api/elements/dom-repeat (pure Polymer) or just plain JS in lit templates if you plan to use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In polymer3 you can achieve that using the below code. Iterating over your data structure and calculating the styles for each item.

```
<dom-repeat items="{{years}}"> 
    <template> 
        <paper-item class$={{getPercentFromLeft(year)}}>{{item}}</paper-item> 
    </template> 
</dom-repeat>
```

---

getPercentFromLeft will be called for each item(year) and you can return the required class.